# Why does my for loop which calls the addLink method not print the proper coefficient and exponent values?

Tags: java, for-loop, methods, polynomials

> The first for loop prints the proper coeffcient and exponent values as
> provided by the value string, but the second for loop which class the
> addLink method does not print the proper values? I cannot see what the
> problem is. Why does the output from the first for loop not match the output from the second?
>
> The code has been edited. I have moved the addLink method into the first for loop and my output is shown below. it is still not what I am intending.

```
public class Polyvalues {
    Term head;

    public Polyvalues() {
        String value = "5 6 8 9 1 9";
        String sub[] = value.split(" ");
        double coeff = 0;
        int exp = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < sub.length; i++) 
        {
            if (sub[i].isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("No input");
            }
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                try {
                    coeff = Double.parseDouble(sub[i]);
                    System.out.println("Coeff is " + coeff);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    System.out.println("Fix This");
                }

            } else {
                try {
                    exp = Integer.parseInt(sub[i]);
                    System.out.println("The exp is " + exp);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    System.out.println("Fix This");
                }
            }
     

          this.addLink(coeff, exp);//moved from commented out for-loop
        }
        System.out.println("*******************************************");
        /*for (int i = 0; i < sub.length; i++)
        {
            this.addLink(coeff, exp);
        }*/ 
        
    }//end constructor
        
    public void addLink(double a, int b)
    {
        if(head == null)
        {
            head = new Term(a,b);
            return;
        }
        Term currNode = head;
        while(currNode.next != null)
        {
            currNode = currNode.next;
        }    
        currNode.next = new Term(a,b);
        //addLink(a,b);
    }
    
    static class Term{
        double coeff;
        int exp;
        Term next;

        Term(double c, int e){
            this.coeff = c;
            this.exp = e;
            this.next = null;
            System.out.println("The Coeff "+ this.coeff);
            System.out.println("The Exp "+ this.exp);
        }    
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Polyvalues p1 = new Polyvalues();
    }
} //end of class
```

[image: Code Output]

> Now, I get this when I move the addLink method into the first for-loop. Why am I getting these duplicate outputs when I print?

[image: Second Output]

> When this is what I want:
> Is it my nodes?

[image: Third Output]

Answer (score 0):

Because in the second loop you are passing the same value of `coeff` and `exp` every time.
At the end of your first loop value of `coeff` is 1.0 and `exp` is 9
and you are passing that same value every time, in the second loop, to method `addLink`.
To solve it either make an array to store every value or just call `addLink` in the first loop.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to learn how to debug your code. Every programmer needs to know how to debug code. Have you read this Web page? [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
In any case, if you are using an IDE (like [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/) or [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)) then it should have a debugger and you should learn to use it.

You are close with your code. You just need to move the call to method `addLink`. (See the below code.) If you step through the code using a debugger, you will understand why. Basically you need to call `addLink` **after** you have obtained a value for **both** `coeff` and `exp`. In your code you are calling `addLink` twice – once when you only have the `coeff` value and the second time when you have both `coeff` and `exp`.

In the below code, I have indicated the change with the comment *Moved from after this 'else' block.* I also left the original line but commented it out.

Also note that I added [overridden] [toString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--) methods just to make it easier to see the results of executing the code.

```java
public class Polyvalues {
    Term head;

    public Polyvalues() {
        String value = "5 6 8 9 1 9";
        String sub[] = value.split(" ");
        double coeff = 0;
        int exp = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < sub.length; i++) {
            if (sub[i].isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("No input");
            }
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                try {
                    coeff = Double.parseDouble(sub[i]);
                    System.out.println("Coeff is " + coeff);
                }
                catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    System.out.println("Fix This");
                }
            }
            else {
                try {
                    exp = Integer.parseInt(sub[i]);
                    System.out.println("The exp is " + exp);
                    this.addLink(coeff, exp); // Moved from after this 'else' block.
                }
                catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    System.out.println("Fix This");
                }
            }
            //this.addLink(coeff, exp);//moved from commented out for-loop
        }
        System.out.println("*******************************************");
    }// end constructor

    public void addLink(double a, int b) {
        if (head == null) {
            head = new Term(a, b);
            return;
        }
        Term currNode = head;
        while (currNode.next != null) {
            currNode = currNode.next;
        }
        currNode.next = new Term(a, b);
        // addLink(a,b);
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Term curr = head;
        while (curr != null) {
            sb.append(curr);
            curr = curr.next;
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    static class Term {
        double coeff;
        int exp;
        Term next;

        Term(double c, int e) {
            this.coeff = c;
            this.exp = e;
            this.next = null;
            System.out.println("The Coeff " + this.coeff);
            System.out.println("The Exp " + this.exp);
        }

        public String toString() {
            return String.format("[C=%.2f,E=%d]-> ", coeff, exp);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Polyvalues p1 = new Polyvalues();
        System.out.println(p1);
    }
} // end of class
```

Running the above code prints the following:

```
Coeff is 5.0
The exp is 6
The Coeff 5.0
The Exp 6
Coeff is 8.0
The exp is 9
The Coeff 8.0
The Exp 9
Coeff is 1.0
The exp is 9
The Coeff 1.0
The Exp 9
The Coeff 1.0
The Exp 9
*******************************************
[C=5.00,E=6]-> [C=8.00,E=9]-> [C=1.00,E=9]-> [C=1.00,E=9]->
```